# React-Native not importing folder

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import everything from a directory in react native but it's giving me an error

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `../actions` from `F:\INSTALLED\React-Native\crm\components\PeopleItem.js`: The module `../actions` could not be found from `F:\INSTALLED\React-Native\crm\components\PeopleItem.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

However The folder name `actions` exists.
Here is my `PeopleItem.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  image
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {getTheme} from 'react-native-material-kit'
import icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import * as actions from '../actions'
```

Here is my Directory Structure
[image]

Comment: are you exporting anything from the index.js file in the actions folder? Paste what your index.js file looks like - the issue might be there

Comment: Is it possible that naming your index.js with capital 'I' could mess the things ?

Comment: @Yesub you're right the problem was capital 'I' I changed it to small and it worked. Thank you, bro.

Comment: Glad it help. I'll add it as answer to help later reader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Index.js` file has to be named with a lower case 'i' as this : `index.js` so the interpreter can interpret it properly as an index file.